# Correct xpath when reading JSON out of MYSQL DB using common_schema.extract_json

Tags: mysql, json, xpath

I am creating a query to re-use periodically to pull data out of a MySQL database (not for use in production code) and want to display values from a JSON object as columns. I installed common_schema and have been using the extract_json function but I can't find the correct xpath to use to get the field I want, I always get null. The query I am using currently is below:

```
SELECT common_schema.extract_json_value(stores.info,'/Region') as "Sales Region" FROM stores
```

An example of the JSON object stored in stores.info is below:

`{"Town":"HDM","Post Code":"003408","Region":"FGH","OutletCode":"AB43G","CustomerCode":"15134158"}`

What xpath do I need to access, for example Region. If the path is correct why is it returning NULL?

Comment: Make sure you have no new line characters  in the json. You call also with spaces. It often happens when there are non UTF8 characters also